# Installing jvisualvm as service giving error

Tags: java, performance, windows-services, windows-server-2012, jvisualvm

I am trying to install **jvisualvm** as **Windows Service** since my **Tomcat** is also running as Windows Service. I ran following command to install jvisualvm as service:

```
sc create jvisualvm binpath= ...(Location for jvisual.exe without quotes("))
```

And I get message of `CreateService SUCCESS`

But when I try to run from Services it is giving me error:

```
Windows could not start the jvisualvm on Local Computer.      
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Can anyone suggest me what can be the cause for this error?

Comment: Whats the purpose of trying to make it a service?  Plus, I didn't think you could run desktop applications as a service.

Comment: @Johnny V Currently if I run jvisualvm it does not automatically detect my application. I have to add as JMX connection, which doesnot allow me to use Profiler. https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as This blog explains if Tomcat is running as Service then you have to add jvisualvm as service too in order to use Profiler.

Comment: have you tried running VisualVM using "Run As Administrator" ?

Comment: @JohnnyV Yes I did. It does not detect Tomcat automatically.